# Displaying date from mysql in a Jquery Mobile dropdown

Tags: mysql, ajax, html, jquery-mobile

I started making an app with use of Jquery mobile(JQM) to be used for a customer database. You should be able to create a customer name, address etc. The information will then be stored in a MySQL database. The part I've got under control. 
Now I want to do so that it is possible to retrieve customer number and name of the database again and show them in a drop down menu from JQM. 
So something like: 
"SELECT 
       `kundenummer`, `navn` 
FROM 
    kundeskema 
ORDER BY 
    id 
DESC";

I have my database connection and my php page, but how do I get the information from where I make my sql statement and to my html page? Know it is using AJAX but dont understand how to do. I know it's a fairly simple task, but it's not for me.

plz help

Morten

Answer (score 4):

You can create a PHP file which returns a JSON string of your data. Then do a jQuery ajax call to this PHP file and in the success callback create  elements and add them the select element.

e.g.:

```
$.ajax({
    url: myValues.php,             
        success: function(data) {                
            template  = //create option elements
            $('#mySelect').html(template);
    }
});
```

Or

https://github.com/tkompare/projects/tree/master/ajaxexample

This is for a listview but the idea is the same